# How to show Call duration in status bar for VOIP call in iOS app?

Tags: ios, iphone, xcode, macos

I am doing VOIP app in iOS. I am able to show, call status if app is in background with Red color. But, i am not able to show the call duration along with red color, like how native does with green color.

But, if call is active in my app and app is in background, i am able to showing call status by showing red color by using with AVAudiorecorder.

But, i need to display the call duration along with call active status bar, i have searched so many websites, but, i did not got any reliable solution.

Any Suggestions.